# Owl Carousel - Disable next button on last slide

Tags: owl-carousel, preventdefault, disable

I just started using Owl Carousel. Noticed that there is a bug in the owl.carousel.js. When using the option slideBy:'page' both prev and next navigation still function when disabled and on the first or last page.

For Example: If I clicked the next arrow and it sent me to the last page of items and I click the next arrow again (even though it's greyed out) it is still clickable and then sends me back to the first page.

Same happens on first page but with the previous arrow.

Anyway to fix this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="thumbnails owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="http://topfreeintro.bdjm5gygfhwdb5d.maxcdn-edge.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/No-Text-Intro-Template-108-160x160.jpg?x84593" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2152/8743/products/CGEAR_CG05Y1101045NP_COMFORT_MAT_FOREST_GREEN_PRODUCT_3_72dpi_c3929ecd-5b2c-4ec3-83aa-c5a37df2badd_160x160.jpg?v=1547876502" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="http://topfreeintro.bdjm5gygfhwdb5d.maxcdn-edge.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/No-Text-Intro-Template-105-160x160.jpg?x84593" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="https://v-play.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/free_music_for_games_purple-planet.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0225/1115/products/textures-free-hand-painted-wall-texture-01-1_compact.jpg?v=1497443190" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61AD6ZRsqAL._AC_UL160_SR160,160_.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="https://www.jesselanewellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Healthy-Dairy-Free-Dessert-Book-Tour-Life-of-Eden.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

    <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/violet-purple-orchid-flowers-decorated-wood-can-be-used-as-background-free-space-your-text-violet-purple-orchid-108412326.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
    </a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.product-gallery .thumbnails {
  margin: 2em 0 0;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.product-gallery .main a {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

**DEMO** [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ryman/sckw5afd/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your owl-next button is grabbing disabled class but the button in itself is still active.

You want your app to disable owl-next button when hitting the last page of your carousel items. You can achieve this using owl event object passing a callback function. [Owl api events](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html)

Try the following:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:false,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    slideBy:'page',
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:4
        },
        600:{
            items:4
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        }
    }
});

$('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {

    $('button.owl-next').removeAttr('disabled');
    $('button.owl-prev').removeAttr('disabled');

    if ( ( e.page.index + 1 ) >= e.page.count ){
        $('button.owl-next').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('button.owl-next').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    
    if ( e.page.index == 0 ){
        $('button.owl-prev').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('button.owl-prev').removeAttr('disabled');
    }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>



<div class="thumbnails owl-carousel owl-theme">
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="http://topfreeintro.bdjm5gygfhwdb5d.maxcdn-edge.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/No-Text-Intro-Template-108-160x160.jpg?x84593" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2152/8743/products/CGEAR_CG05Y1101045NP_COMFORT_MAT_FOREST_GREEN_PRODUCT_3_72dpi_c3929ecd-5b2c-4ec3-83aa-c5a37df2badd_160x160.jpg?v=1547876502" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="http://topfreeintro.bdjm5gygfhwdb5d.maxcdn-edge.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/No-Text-Intro-Template-105-160x160.jpg?x84593" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="https://v-play.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/free_music_for_games_purple-planet.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0225/1115/products/textures-free-hand-painted-wall-texture-01-1_compact.jpg?v=1497443190" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61AD6ZRsqAL._AC_UL160_SR160,160_.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="https://www.jesselanewellness.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Healthy-Dairy-Free-Dessert-Book-Tour-Life-of-Eden.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
        <a class="thumbnail " title="" href="">
          <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/t/violet-purple-orchid-flowers-decorated-wood-can-be-used-as-background-free-space-your-text-violet-purple-orchid-108412326.jpg" alt="The Gwen Teething Toy - Thumbnail TEST">
        </a>
        
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this it worked for me

```
 $('#owl-carousel .carousel-items-wrapper').owlCarousel({
        loop:false,
        nav:true,
        dots: false,
        navText:["<i class='icon-feather-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='icon-feather-chevron-right'></i>"],
        margin:20, 
        autoplay:false,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:2
            },
            1000:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    });
   
 $('#owl-carousel .carousel-items-wrapper').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(e) {
   var items     = e.item.count;     // Number of items
   var item      = e.item.index;     // Position of the current item
   var size      = e.page.size;      // Number of items per page
  

  // You can make this work by hiding/showing it via jQuery 
  // or we add a custom-class to it
   $(this).find(".owl-prev").show();
   $(this).find(".owl-next").show();
   // OR
   // $(this).find(".owl-prev").removeClass("owl-nav-hidden");
   // $(this).find(".owl-next").removeClass("owl-nav-hidden");

   if(item == 0){
      console.log("We have reached the beginning...");
      $(this).find(".owl-prev").hide();
      // OR
      // $(this).find(".owl-prev").addClass("owl-nav-hidden");
   }
   if(item == (items - size)){
      console.log("We have reached the End...");
      $(this).find(".owl-next").hide();
      // OR
      // $(this).find(".owl-next").addClass("owl-nav-hidden");

   }

});
```